# Is there a way to made the name of a dataframe a variable that is defined by the user?

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, variables

The user would enter in the date. I would then like the name of the dataframe to be table_date. I get the following error when I try running the code. SyntaxError: cannot assign to f-string expression

```
date = "199101"

data = {'Start Date':  ['1', '2', '3'],
        'End Date': ['2', '3','33'],
        'Days Between': ['3', '3', '33' ],
        'Weeks Between': ['7', '8', '4'],
        'Months Between': ['.5', '.6', '.2']
        }

"table_"f"{date}" = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Start Date','End Date','Days Between', 'Weeks Between', 'Months Between'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're assigning the dataframe to a string rather than to a variable. You can only assign objects to variables. Additionally, Pandas DataFrames don't have titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
>>> globals()["table_"f"{date}"] = pd.DataFrame(...)
```

create the variable `table_199101` in global namespace but I must advise you this is really not a good practice!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why is this not recommended and is there an alternative?